# How to split linked list into 2 list?

Tags: c, list, split

In my code , there are 2 lists. I want to split them : even and odd.
I wrote somethings. But, it did not print what I want. What will i do ?

```
if((list->data) % 2 == 1){
    oddList = list;
    list = list->nextPtr;
    oddList->nextPtr = NULL;
    printList(oddList);
} else {
    evenList = list;
    list = list->nextPtr;
    evenList->nextPtr = NULL;
}
list = list->nextPtr;
```

Result is:

```
list1 : 4 17 17 19 21 28 31 
list2 : 5 5 10 14 19 31 34 35 
oddList : 5 17 19 31 31 
evenlist :
```

But `oddList` must be: `5 5 17 17 19 19 21 31 31 35`

Comment: Just think about how you start a list and what must be done to insert an element from one list and what must be done to remove an element. Once you have that figured out it should be easy.

Comment: @RedX I know, but in my code when i run it , it didn't print same numbers. E.g : it must print 5 5 17 17  19 21  but  it prints 5 17 19

Comment: I think good to is to create a list to copy the elements from lead to destructively modifies the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are advancing `list` twice

```
    if ((list->data) % 2 == 1) {
        oddList = list;
        list = list->nextPtr;            // first advance
        oddList->nextPtr = NULL;
        printList(oddList);
    } else {
        evenList = list;
        list = list->nextPtr;            // first advance
        evenList->nextPtr = NULL;
    }
    list = list->nextPtr;                // second advance
}
```

Comment: Now i delete second advance, for odd list it works true .Now i try for even list. Thank you so much

Comment: but now  i can't print it even list . Do i create a new function for it ??

Comment: `printList()` should be able to print **ANY** list.

Comment: my printList function like that : : :  void printList(struct node *np){
  while(np){
 printf(" %d ",np->data );
 np=np->nextPtr;
  }
}

Comment: and printList print every list correctly. But even list :/

Comment: In you original code, both `evenList` and `oddList` will have at most 1 element. This doesn't look correct.

Comment: OK , i agree with you something are not correct . :So, what is your advice what can i do ? Do you think i create a new method for eveen list ?

Comment: My advice is to create a function to move an element from one list into another. Then use that function.